# What do the Italic Purple colored Words/Methods mean in this code/context?

Tags: java, android

```
 protected static final String GET = HttpGet.METHOD_NAME;
    protected static final String POST = HttpPost.METHOD_NAME;
    protected static final String PUT = HttpPut.METHOD_NAME;
    protected static final String PATCH = HttpPatch.METHOD_NAME;
    protected static final String DELETE = HttpDelete.METHOD_NAME;
    protected static final String TAG = Api.class.getSimpleName();
    protected static final DefaultHttpClient mClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    protected static final int MAX_LOG_LENGTH = 1024;
    protected static final int JSON_LOG_INDENT_SPACES = 2;
```

### In Android Studio:

PS: The meaning of italic purple marked words that are: POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, TAG, METHOD_NAME, mClient, MAX_LOG_LENGTH, JSON_LOG_INDENT_SPACES

I need to know this set of information in order to proceed to delete using HttpDelete for deleting an api_token from which I've created that is as follows:

```
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... strings) {

        JSONObject json = null;

        String str = "";
        HttpResponse response = null;
        HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost("http://safetysupport.test.empoly.nl/api/private/v1/api_token");
        HttpDelete 
        myConnection.addHeader("Authorization", "Token token=\"HXC4eKKkt4k*H&QXRtKK64?ol_npckBRYRt9jLt-E8$WjkJWf*SPN+Xnv3K_75wn\"");
        myConnection.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        JSONObject input = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject api_token = new JSONObject();
        try {
            api_token.put("description", strings[0]);
            input.put("api_token", api_token);
            myConnection.setEntity(new JSONEntity(input));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
            str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);
            json = jsonObject.getJSONObject("api_token");


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return json;
    }
```

Where I need to further edit the HttpDelete to a deleting function, but I don't know what word/method/context/code/constant field that comes after it ?! :(

Please help, any help would be appreciated !

Kind Regards,

Comment: Don't mix up editors and languages. The formatting of the text probably has little to do with your actual question, which I guess is what the keywords mean. It's fairly easy to see what those variables have in common btw, and my guess would be that you get special colors from `final`.

Answer (score 2):

Your IDE is simply just color-coding the variable names in each line **based on your syntax color coding-style preferences.** *These can generally be changed in your preferences panel. Eclipse for Example: Eclipse > Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring*

**To answer your question:**
*POST, PUT PATCH, DELETE, TAG, mClient, MAX_LOG_LENGTH and JSON_LOG_INDENT_SPACES* are the names of the variables. They are finals so they can only be initialized once.

METHOD_NAME is the name of a method that you are accessing (and setting the above "purple-colored" variables equal to) - located in the HttpDelete class.

It looks like you are using *Android Studio* and by default I beleive that it sets static variables and methods *purple*.

*Remember,* This is just a preferences set in your IDE and purple is not generally considered indicative of a "static" variable.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're talking about Android Studio.
The italic and purple colored statements in the variables declaration are named "Static Variables".

Static variables are those associated with the class and not the objects that are created by this class. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) you can find more about them.

I would like to point what keyser suggested in his comment:
The color and the styling of the statements in each editor has nothing to do with their semantics. What I mean is that in different editors (e.g. Eclipse) the same statement will be displayed differently. The semantics of the element is what the language wants to describe with that element. The color/styling is what the editor does to help your eyes/brain locate same semantics.

EDIT:
It's not clear to mean if the above answers your question or what you really ask is what is GET, PUT, ... in terms of functionality.
In this case [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html) you can find the Javadoc of the HttpGet class where it says:

> String getMethod()
>
> Returns the HTTP method this request uses, such as GET, PUT, POST, or other.

You can look for the rest in the same website.

Comment: How do I know what constant/static variable belongs to whom ? when I create say     HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();       myClient  for example how do I know its myClient and not something else ?

Comment: like is "my" a standard static variable ?

Comment: Cause I want a list that proceeds the word HttpDelete  in the code that I'm at the moment trying to program

Comment: I think that you definitely need to read a book/online resources about Object Oriented Programming. I can't answer these questions here. You need to do you own research first and if you can't find the answer, we all are more than happy to help. I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Those are constants, and some of them are not very useful as they are referencing other constants, like:

```
protected static final String GET = HttpGet.METHOD_NAME;
```

That's basically the same as using "HttpGet.METHOD_NAME" in your code instead of "GET", but may be clearer for you.